# Creating a Date Table with Powerquery in Excel for a 13 Period Fiscal Year, with a twist

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I needed to make a date table for our company's Fiscal Year in Powerquery to pull into Excel for some analysis- and had success with the following code:

```
 ( FirstFYDate as date, optional StartOfWeekDay as number, optional AddYears as number, optional Holidays as list ) as table =>
    let
        FYStartDate = FirstFYDate, // #date(2019, 9, 29), // Enter your first FY StartDate here
        StartOfWeekNum = if List.Contains({0..6}, StartOfWeekDay) then StartOfWeekDay else 0, // Day.Sunday =0, Day.Monday =1 etc
        CurrentDate = Date.From( DateTimeZone.FixedUtcNow()),
        ExtendYears = if AddYears = null or AddYears =0 then Date.Year( CurrentDate ) -  Date.Year( FYStartDate ) +1 else AddYears,
        StartDate = Number.From( FYStartDate ),
        EndDate = StartDate + ( 364 * ExtendYears ) -1,
        ListDates = {StartDate..EndDate},
        ConvertedToTable = Table.FromList(ListDates, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
        RenamedColumns = Table.RenameColumns(ConvertedToTable,{{"Column1", "DateKey"}}),
        DateKey = Table.TransformColumnTypes(RenamedColumns,{{"DateKey", type date}}),
        DayID = Table.AddIndexColumn(DateKey, "DayID", 1, 1),
        YearID = Table.AddColumn(DayID, "YearID", each Number.RoundDown(([DayID]-1)/364)+1, Int64.Type),
        //QuarterID = Table.AddColumn(YearID, "QuarterID", each Number.RoundDown(([DayID]-1)/91)+1, Int64.Type),
        MonthID = Table.AddColumn(YearID, "MonthID", each Number.RoundDown(([DayID]-1)/28)+1, Int64.Type),
        WeekID = Table.AddColumn(MonthID, "WeekID", each Number.RoundDown(([DayID]-1)/7)+1, Int64.Type),
        InsertYear = Table.AddColumn(WeekID, "Year", each Date.Year([DateKey]), Int64.Type),
        InsertMonth = Table.AddColumn(InsertYear, "Month", each Date.Month([DateKey]), Int64.Type),
        InsertDayOfMonth = Table.AddColumn(InsertMonth, "Day", each Date.Day([DateKey]), Int64.Type),
        InsertMonthName = Table.AddColumn(InsertDayOfMonth, "Month Name", each Date.MonthName([DateKey]), type text),
        InsertEndOfMonth = Table.AddColumn(InsertMonthName, "End of Month", each Date.EndOfMonth([DateKey]), type date),
        InsertDayName = Table.AddColumn(InsertEndOfMonth, "Day Name", each Date.DayOfWeekName([DateKey]), type text),
        StartOfWeek = Table.AddColumn(InsertDayName, "Start of Week", each Date.StartOfWeek([DateKey], StartOfWeekNum), type date),
        EndOfWeek = Table.AddColumn(StartOfWeek, "End of Week", each Date.EndOfWeek([DateKey], StartOfWeekNum), type date),
        InsertYearFY = Table.AddColumn(EndOfWeek, "FY Year", each Date.Year( FYStartDate ) + [YearID], Int64.Type ),
        InsertPeriodFY = Table.AddColumn(InsertYearFY, "FY Period", each [MonthID] - (( [YearID] -1 ) * 13 ), Int64.Type ),
        InsertWeekFY = Table.AddColumn(InsertPeriodFY, "FY Week", each [WeekID] - (( [YearID] -1 ) * 52 ), Int64.Type),
        InsertDayOfFY = Table.AddColumn(InsertWeekFY, "FY Day", each [DayID] - (( [YearID] -1 ) * 364 ), Int64.Type),
        InsertFYPeriod = Table.AddColumn(InsertDayOfFY, "FY & Period", each Text.From([FY Year]) & "-" & Text.PadStart(Text.From([FY Period]), 2, "0"), type text),
        InsertFYWeek = Table.AddColumn(InsertFYPeriod, "FY & Week", each Text.From([FY Year]) & "-" & Text.PadStart(Text.From([FY Week]), 2, "0"), type text),
        InsertIsAfterToday = Table.AddColumn(InsertFYWeek, "IsAfterToday", each not ([DateKey] <= Date.From(CurrentDate)), type logical),
        InsertIsWorkingDay = Table.AddColumn(InsertIsAfterToday, "IsWorkingDay", each if Date.DayOfWeek([DateKey], Day.Monday) > 4 then false else true, type logical),
        InsertIsHoliday = Table.AddColumn(InsertIsWorkingDay, "IsHoliday", each if Holidays = null then "Unknown" else List.Contains( Holidays, [DateKey] ), if Holidays = null then type text else type logical)
    in
        InsertIsHoliday
```

However, this year our company stated that our fiscal year will have an extra week in the 13th period, leading to this code not outputting what I need.

I am unsure of the convention that this Fiscal Year calendar follows, if there is any.

Our start date is 09/25/2022 and end date is 09/30/2023.

Hoping that someone else might have dealt with a similar situation that would have some insight, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try anything at all? How about

```
EndDate = StartDate + ( 364 * ExtendYears ) -1+7,


YearID = Table.AddColumn(DayID, "YearID", each Number.RoundDown(([DayID]-1)/371)+1, Int64.Type),


InsertDayOfFY = Table.AddColumn(InsertWeekFY, "FY Day", each [DayID] - (( [YearID] -1 ) * 371 ), Int64.Type),
```